# Galaxy S7 edge - How do I use a sound downloaded as part of a theme?

Tags: alarm, ringtone, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge, themes

I want to use the sounds I have downloaded as part of my theme (Blue Polygon) as my ringtone and alarm sound. However, it is not in the selection of sounds when I tried to change it.

Please advice. I have no root access.

Comment: @beeshyams Hey, the sounds might be stored in the theme folder I believe, which requires root access.

Comment: @beeshyams A theme is not an apk though.

Comment: Van you link the theme in your question?

Comment: @beeshyams http://www.samsung.com/global/themestore/index.html?appId=com.echovisuals.www.BluePolygon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have asked the developers and found out that this is a bug caused by setting one or more of the sound settings (notification, ringtone and volume) to silent.

To fix it, follow these steps:

1. Start by going to Settings - Themes, select the theme named "Default", and then apply.
2. After this, go through all of your settings and make sure nothing is set to Silent.
3. Once this is verified, re-apply the theme and it should be working.